# How can i get element width / height in modal ( bootstrap )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get element width / height after modal shown ( bootstrap )

```
var elWidth = $('.game-wrapper.gw-modal').width();
```

When I doing like this I'm getting **-60** width. 
but real width when modal shown **(for ex. 730px )** - col-md-8

Comment: get the width AFTER the modal is open

Comment: aww 
i selected show.bs.modal but need shown.bs.modal

Comment: is element has both class like 'game-wrapper gw-modal'?

Comment: Yeah. problem was with modal event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shown.bs.modal event

> This event is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete). If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: waiting 7 minutes :)